# What is a good open source or .net component to create an email client

Tags: .net, email-client

I have come across these .net components and want to know if anyone has used them before or know of anything better.

1. [Mailbee](http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/email-components)
2. [Chilkat](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/email-dotnet.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I currently use MailBee for a in-house email processing application. The API is pretty easy to work with and I found the documentation to be pretty useful.